# ReactNative real native navigation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mobile, react-native

Who can tell me about native navigation on ReactNative? Like a push new activity in java (instagram app use it). I don't know, maybe it already exist, but i didn't find it. Generally, i want real native navigation with native transition. That's all. Thanks.

UPD. Like this: https://youtu.be/qXpYZ6ZbXao?t=7m39s

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using Navigator component from React Native. As I read in iOS it uses NavigationController itself, I don't know in Android but it feels the app uses native navigation. It provides all transitions. You can follow the link [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)

Comment: I use it. Pushing to components looks like not native. Of cource you can set any transitions, but it's not what I want. Like this: https://youtu.be/qXpYZ6ZbXao?t=7m39s

Comment: Actually the video is showing Xamarin form and it has its own navigation and animations. If you looking same as in video then you should create a custom transition for this. And in iOS app navigators working fine with transitions.Thanks

Comment: okay, what you can say about not Xamarin apps? Like Instagram. There have navigation between components like from the video. I don't know how it work in Java, but want to use it in RN.